# How to open a file in the current open Eclipse workspace from command line?

Tags: eclipse, command-line-interface

I have Eclipse already running, and I want to be able to open a file and jump to a line number from CLI.

I want the file to open in the current open workspace. I am trying this:

```
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse --launcher.openFile test_file.c:401
```

However, I am getting an error because the default workspace is already open, and its asking me to choose another workspace.

if I simply use `open text_file.c` it works just fine, but doesn't jump to the line number of course.

**Edit:** Even after starting in a new session, and removing the line number, Eclipse doesn't open the file. It only opens the application (Eclipse).
however if I use `open -a eclipse filename` the file opens successfully

Comment: The line suffix is a feature that does not yet exist in Eclipse. You might report it as a feature request, preferably with contributing an implementation for that.

Comment: @howlger I just found out that even if I remove the line number, eclipse opens (has to be another session) but the file never opens.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I've been using this feature (without line numbers) for years (I integrated it into the right-click menu) without any problems.

Comment: @howlger on mac?

Comment: If you look into the code, you can find that out for yourself, if that matters here. It's unclear to me what exactly works for you and what doesn't. A detailed step-by-step instruction would be helpful (where do you type what exactly with which actual vs. expected result; macOS and Eclipse version; etc.).

Comment: @Shadi: One situation in which you can get this problem is if the running Eclipse instance is different from the one you are trying to launch. That would explain why `open -a eclipse filename` works correctly but using the full path to the `eclipse` executable does not. Have you verified that the running Eclipse instance is the same as `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`?

Comment: @Lili, yes. its the same :( I also do not have more than 1 instance on this setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lili for the correction:

1. Opening a file in the same workspace via command line does not work on mac, bug[1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564340)

2. Opening a file/linenumber in eclipse is not supported

Comment: This seems to be a problem for Mac only. I can successfully use this feature on Windows 10 with Eclipse 2020-06. So I don't think it's accurate to say "this is not yet supported". It looks like a bug to me.